# Asking to write a sentence in a loop to count vowels, won't ask again even when the loop goes on

Tags: c++

Title might be a bit confusing, I tried to be as specific as I could

Hi, total c++ beginner here, trying to make work a simple program that should tell me how many vowels a sentence contains. Problem here is the loop is not asking me to write a sentence like it should when it continues after the first iteration.

So basically here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i, nb_vowels, cont=1;
    char sentence[100];

    while(cont!=0){
        cout << "Enter a sentence : ";

        while ((sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n') {
            i++;
            if(sentence[i]=='a' || sentence[i]=='e'|| sentence[i]=='i' || sentence[i]=='o' || sentence[i]=='u'){
                nb_vowels++;
            }
        }
        sentence[i] = '\0';

        cout << "Number of vowels : " << nb_vowels <<endl;

        cout << "1 to continue or 0 to stop : ";
        cin >> cont;
    }   
}
```

Here's an example of how it goes when I execute it :

```
Enter a sentence : hello i am learning c++
Number of vowels : 1  //that part is still not working btw, but i want to know how to fix the loop problem first
1 to continue or 0 to stop : 1
Enter a sentence : Number of vowels : 1 //i cant write anything here, it just pops like that
1 to continue or 0 to stop :
```

Here's how it should go :

```
Enter a sentence : hello i am learning c++
Number of vowels : 6
1 to continue or 0 to stop : 1
Enter a sentence : wooo it works
Number of vowels : 1
1 to continue or 0 to stop : 0
```

I'm kind of lost right now as I know so little about C++ (only started a few days ago), any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `i` is not initialized properly. You should have easily found out if you had done as I recommended above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not posting here often, I'll make sure to do what you recommended above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `i` and `nb_vowels` are not initialized to anything, initialize properly like: `int nb_vowels = 0, i = 0;`

Secondly, why don't you use `cin.getline(sentence, 100);` to input a sentence, why looping yourself to do this task?

And if you use `cin.getline`, you'd have to add an `cin.ignore();` after your input of `cin >> cont;`

Here's the code you can use to perform this task:

```
int cont = 1;
int nb_vowels = 0;
char sentence[100];
while (cont != 0){
    cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
    cin.getline(sentence, 100);
    int sentenceSize = strlen(sentence);
    for (int i = 0; i < sentenceSize; i++){
        if (sentence[i] == 'a' || sentence[i] == 'e'|| sentence[i] == 'i' || sentence[i] == 'o' || sentence[i] == 'u')
            nb_vowels++;
    }
    cout << "No. of Vowels: " << nb_vowels << endl;
    cout << "1 to continue or 0 to stop : ";
    cin >> cont;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Better yet, you should use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) instead of `char` array. Read about the `string`, it's pretty simple, if you'd have any problem regarding that, first search about that problem, and then come with some real problem.

Comment: Better yet, use a `std::string`, not a char array. Then only getline would be necessary, like this: `getline(sentence)`, and `sentence.length()` for the length of the sentence.

Comment: Yes absolutely, let me add it to my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

use `fflush(stdin);` before `cout<<"no of vowels"`